# Корректно ли передавать объекту, реализующему паттерн Стратегия указатель на объект, который его содержит

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Допустим, есть класс реализующий базу данных, и у него есть метод, проверяющий текущее соединение:

```
class Database 
{

public:
    ...
    void checkConnection();
};
```

Предположим, класс предусматривает различные способы загрузки данных в базу, например, асинхронный и синхронный. Для реализации подобной возможности загрузка делегируется классу, выполняющему роль Стратегии:

```
class DbLoader 
{
public:
 ...
void loadData();
};
```

Но в `loadData` перед началом загрузки необходимо проверить соединение, поэтому нужно передать указатель на класс его содержащий, чтобы использовать метод `checkConnection`. Допустимо ли так поступать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратившись к классике, а именно к книге Банды четырех, нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Цитата оттуда:

> классы Strategy и Context взаимодействуют для реализации выбранного
>   алгоритма. Контекст может передать стратегии все необходимые алгоритму
>   данные на момент вызова. Вместо этого контекст может позволить
>   обращаться к своим операциям в нужные моменты, передав ссылку на
>   самого себя операциям класса Strategy.